# Gradle issue while adding

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to add glide new version but I am getting these errors

I don't understand why this is happening

I am updating `glide` because this version of `glide` does not load GIF smoothly

[image]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rayvatapps.inspiquo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 7
        versionName "2.5"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2'
    //cardview
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.0'
    //recyclerview
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.0'
    //glide
//    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0'
    //voley
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    //gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    //sdp
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    //ripple effect
    implementation 'com.skyfishjy.ripplebackground:library:1.0.1'
    //glide new
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.7.1'
}
```

If I add old version than it's work fine while updating with a newer version it's not working

Comment: Are you sure is this a glide issue. Because in your console it says fontStyle missing?

Comment: yes if I remove new version of glide than it's work's fine

Comment: update compileSdkVersion,targetSdkVersion, support library version to 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
compileSdkVersion 27
targetSdkVersion 27


implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:72.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
//implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
//cardview
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
//recyclerview
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
//glide
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
//voley
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
//gson
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
```

Add this to your project level build.gradle

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
}
```

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

use this
**compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'**

---

if you are used sdk version 28 then
**implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.5.2'**

Comment: implementation vs compile has nothing to do with the SDK version - it has to do with the version of Gradle.